# How to add external libraries to custom runtime image using jlink?

Tags: java, jlink

I want to add external libraries needed by my project to the **custom runtime image**.

I use the following external libraries in my project: **vlcj.jar, vlcj-javafx.jar**

For **vlcj.jar** to work I also need to add external libraries: **jna.jar, jna-platform.jar, vlcj-natives.jar**

If I rewrite my application so that I don't need to use vlcj.jar and vlcj-javafx.jar, then the custom runtime image creation line looks like this:

```
jlink --no-header-files --no-man-pages --compress=2 --strip-debug --module-path 'path/to/javafx-jmods-15.0.1' --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.web --output /path/to/RuntimeImage
```

Then I create the jar of my application:

```
cd path/to/myapp
jar cvfe path/to/myApp.jar MainClass *.*
```

Then I add **myApp.jar** to the **RuntimeImage** and run the app with:

```
cd path/to/RuntimeImage
path/to/RuntimeImage/bin/java -jar myApp.jar
```

The application starts up. Things are good.

The only bad thing is that it works without **VLCJ**.
How can I add external **VLCJ** libraries to the **custom runtime image** and run my application with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom runtime image does not support automatic modules (non-module jars) so you don't have any dependent jars in the `jlink` image which defines classpath for running with the vlc.

You can edit the `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` in your own jar to specify a classpath so the extra jars could be read from the same directory you run `java -jar`:

```
Class-Path: vlcj.jar vlcj-javafx.jar jna.jar jna-platform.jar vlcj-natives.jar
```

Alternatively switch to standard launch for your application with explicit classpath:

```
path/to/RuntimeImage/bin/java -cp myApp.jar:vlcj.jar:vlcj-javafx.jar:jna.jar:jna-platform.jar:vlcj-natives.jar your.MainClass
```

Comment: How do you launch and what is the error? If Class-Path does not specify absolute paths then the those jars must be in the same directory as the pathname specified for myApp.jar parameter, and myApp.jar must exist at that path too.

Comment: I found a solution to the problem I wrote about in the deleted comment. It was necessary to add another module to the RuntimeImage. Thanks for the help. Now trying to do this with jpackage

Comment: Note that JPackage deals with classpath automatically for jars bundled into into your jpackage image (--input imgdir) but will only see modules added by jlink in the bundled JVM runtime image.

Comment: How do I then add vlcj jars? I tried adding them using --input path/to/myApp.jarAndVlcjJars. The app launches but VLCJ doesn't work.